# Can i use nodejs to quit another application?

Tags: node.js

Can i use nodejs to quit / exit a completely different application or program, for example paint.exe?

I've been trying a lot of different search queries for this and i find it strange that this question has never been asked before (it seems to me)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can,

First you need to determine the PID of the process.
Then you can [kill it](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-process-kill-method/) with `process.kill(pid)`

To find the PID, I would recommend this `ps-list` npm package. It has a `psList` function which lists the active processes.

```
import psList from 'ps-list';

async function killProcess(name) {
    const processes = await psList()
    const match = processes.find(p => p.name === name);
    if (match) process.kill(match.pid)
}

killProcess('mspaint.exe');
```